# Movie where a woman wakes up in an alternate life where she's married to the man she secretly loves and is the only one who remembers her old life

Tags: story-identification, movie

Years ago (early 2000s, I think) I watched a scene in a movie where a woman is secretly in love with a man who is married with children. One day, she wakes up and is now his wife and the mother of his child; the woman who was previously his wife now has the life the main character had before. Everybody acts like it's totally normal, but the main character remembers that her life used to be different. Also, she was a friend of that family; I think the kids named her "aunt Jeanine" or something similar.

I also remember that the main character was secretly in love with this man because she was a friend of his wife or something like that. She was like a spinster and secretly envied her friend for being married to him. In the scene I remember, she wakes up, goes downstairs, and finds the man in the kitchen, who greets her affectionately. She asks him something like "you were not married to ..?" And he went like "??? Why her???". Then she realizes that he changed his life with his wife.

Comment: In Blake Crouch's novel [Recursion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/42046112-recursion), it is exactly the other way around. A successful but lonely business woman suddenly remembers an alternate life in which she has a husband and a kid. She tries to confront the man who she remembers as a husband. He denies it, although she gets the feeling he knows more than he lets on.

Comment: Plots similar to this are highly reusable for being predictably heartwarming crowd pleasers. If you remember anything distinctive about the actors or setting it may help. Hair color, accent, styles of dress, or anything else that stuck with you no matter how small it may seem.

Comment: A quick search in Google for "movie where a woman wakes up in alternate life" gave up some promising results: ["Family for Christmas"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4766018/) and ["Comfort and Joy"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0383278/); "Holidaze" also appears but it has been discarded from the answers. Funnily enough, all three movies are "christmas" movies...

Answer (score 10):

It's a little later than the early 2000s, but I wonder if this could be *[Holidaze](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2622122/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)*, a film from 2012 starring Jennie Garth as a hard-working corporate executive named Melody Gerard. The summary from IMDB shows that it satisfies most of the points in the question:

> Melody, high powered corporate workaholic for a retail conglomerate,
> is happy to spend the holidays jet-setting with her girlfriends.
> However, she's in for an unpleasant surprise when her boss sends her
> to her sleepy hometown to convince the reluctant townspeople to allow
> them to build a new discount store. Now, forced to reconnect with her
> family and her childhood sweetheart Carter, her task is not so simple,
> as all are vehemently opposed to everything Melody's company stands
> for. Desperate to get out of town and back to her real life, Melody
> takes a spill and wakes up in an alternate universe where she never
> left home and is married to Carter! Once determined to leave her small
> town life behind, Melody must make sense of her new life and decide if
> you truly can go home again.

While she is in the alternate reality, she meets her best friend from high school, Jen. Possibly this is the "Jeanine" mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but I dont think its that movie. I truly remember that the main character was secretly in love with this man because she was a friend of his wife or something like that. She was like a spinster and secretly envy his friend for being married to him. In the scene I remember, she wakes up and goes down stairs, find the man at te kitchen who greets her affectiinately. She ask him something like "you where not married to ..?" And he went like ??? Why her??? there she realizes that he changed his life with his wife

Comment: I apologize if something is not well understood, I am not a native English speaker

Answer (score 10):

The details are not completely accurate, but could it be the 1999 film [Me Myself I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me_Myself_I_(film))?

The main plot points that almost match are:

- Pamela Drury (Rachel Griffiths) has a crush on Ben Monroe (Sandy Winton) who has a family, and also wonders about what her life would have been like if she had stayed with her ex-boyfriend Robert (David Roberts).
- She meets and swaps lives with a version of herself who *did* get married to Robert and had children, but winds up having an affair with Ben, who in this reality never married.

The main non-match is that she doesn't wind up becoming Ben's wife (and nor are her children in the alternate reality the ones she saw with him originally). The film also didn't have a wide release outside of Australia so if you saw it in the USA it's less likely to be this.

Answer (score 1):

The described scene reminds me of the [2020 Movie Fantasy Island](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0983946/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), which is a remake of the original [1977 TV series Fantasy Island](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077008/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2). However, I can't say, if this scene actually also was part of the original TV series.

In both the movie and TV series, the protagonists visit an island, where they can live out their deepest fantasies.

In the movie, at least, a woman then goes on to live the life with a lover, she always secretly wanted and have children with him.

Turns out, there is also a [1998 TV series](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0158408/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4) and a [2021 TV series](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13784584/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3) with the same premises and possibly the scene is to be found in one of those.

Comment: If you could find a link to the scene it would help narrow the scope of your answer, and of course it would help the OP too

Comment: There was nothing actually supernatural going on in the series though, was there?

Comment: @fez: I would love to, but I doubt, OP saw the scene in the 2020 movie, if at all in a product of this franchise. Michael Richardson: I did not see the series, so I wouldn't know, however the 2020 movie is very much supernatural.